# Need help to form Regex

Tags: regex

Assume I have a data like this,

"drinks and drums"

I need to fetch string matches which starts with 'd' and ends with 's'.
The Regex which i used,

```
d.*s
```

But it gives the whole string as a match. I need two matches as a result.

Comment: What language are you using ? In your case I will split the sentence into a array or a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match on "word chars", like this:

```
\bd\w+s\b
```

You need the word boundaries, otherwise you'll match `"dyss"` in `"odyssey"`.

Comment: Thanks. But, it is not working if the data is like, https://localhost:8080/somerandomfile.txt. Particularly after ':' expression

Comment: What exactly is the input text and what do you want to match in it? Do you want to match "words", or something else?

Comment: I have an xml file which will have multiple URI's like mentioned above. From that, I need to get only matched URI's. Take the above URI as an example. The Regex will be "https:\\\w+\.txt" [As per your suggestion ]but, it is not giving the above URI as a result

Comment: @code so you wwant to match "domfile"? Which starts with "d"? If not, do you want to match the whole URL? Please be specific about what part of the url you want to match.

Comment: Never mind..I realized that , i need to neglect whitespace. Hence, i used something like this d[^ ]*s which gave me an expected result. Anyway, thanks a lot.